# Can't find some values in array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a array of strings, each string is built with the form `"<x> <y>"`. if `y` starts on a `'n'`, it seems my program is not be be able to find it.

So, the strings that don't work are.

```
"w north",
"w n",
"walk n",
"walk north"
```

Can you help to explain why?

```
string[] next = { "next", "ne", "nx", "nxt" };
string[] yes = { "yes", "y" };
string[] no = { "no", "n" };
string[] clear = { "clear", "c" };
string[] help = { "help", "h" };
string[] walk = 
        { 
            "w north", 
            "w south",
            "w west",
            "w east",
            "w n",
            "w s",
            "w w",
            "w e",
            "walk north",
            "walk south",
            "walk west",
            "walk east" ,
            "walk n",
            "walk s",
            "walk w",
            "walk e"
        };

//Checks if any input match the arrays
public string Input(string input)
{
    input = input.ToLower();
    if (next.Any(input.Contains))
    {
        return "next";
    }
    else if (yes.Any(input.Contains))
    {
        return "yes";
    }
    else if (no.Any(input.Contains))
    {
        return "no";
    }
    else if (clear.Any(input.Contains))
    {
        return "clear";
    }
    else if (help.Any(input.Contains))
    {
        return "help";
    }
    else if (walk.Any(input.Contains))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("test input");
        Location C_locations = new Location();
        C_locations.Change_location(input);
        return "walk";
    }
    else
    {
        return "not found";
    }
}
```

The strings: `"w north"`, `"w n"`, `"walk n"` and `"walk north"`, should run this part of code:

```
else if (walk.Any(input.Contains))
{
    MessageBox.Show( "test input" );
    Location C_locations = new Location();
    C_locations.Change_location( input );
    return "walk";
}
```

Comment: If you fully flesh out your questions before submitting, it will help to get the right answer and prevent any closures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your code does not work is in the content of your `no` array: it contains a single-letter string `"n"`. It is this string that makes

```
no.Any( input.Contains )
```

evaluate to `True` for any input string that contains letter `'n'`.

In order to fix this problem, you can move the checks for `walk` to the top of the `if`/`then`/`else` chain. However, the solution would not be overly robust: `"yellow"` would be classified as `"yes"`, `"cat"` would become `"clear"`, and so on.